# Elasticsearch Cluster set up problems

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building a cluster with elasticsearch. I download the elasticsearch file as a zip file and unzip it in the /opt file. And these are the two IPs I am using for trial, 172.16.30.51 and 172.16.30.52.

I have come across with some problems.  I have tried to amend the host files and add server IP.

> sudo vi /etc/hosts

```
172.16.30.51 elasticnode01
172.16.30.52 elasticnode02
```

Also, in Server elasticnode01 :

> cd /opt/elasticsearch
>
> vi config/elasticsearch.yml

I amend the following code.

```
cluster.name: mycluster
node.name: "elasticnode01"
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["elasticnode02"]
```

In Server elasticnode02 :

> cd /opt/elasticsearch
>
> vi config/elasticsearch.yml

I amend the following code.

```
cluster.name: mycluster
node.name: "elasticnode02"
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["elasticnode01"]
```

Then finally I run the command

> bin/elasticsearch &

It seems fine but as soon as I run

> curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v'

It returns

```
host       ip        heap.percent ram.percent load node.role master name  
    
127.0.0.1  127.0.0.1            4          39 0.20 d         *      elasticnode01
```

Would anyone mind telling me what is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: So, where is the problem you feel? precise it.
Did you configure `elasticsearch.yml` file on `network.host:127.0.0.1`

Comment: Yes, I have configured the file. It seems that it can't diagnose another server/ node. When I curl -X Get 'localhost:9200' on each server, it can only diagnose their own node but not also another server node

Comment: Did you run elasticsearch on both server?

Comment: Yes, I run in both server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since ES 2.0, the ES server [binds to localhost by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_network_changes.html#_bind_to_localhost), so they won't be able to discover each other.

You need to configure `network.host` on both servers, like this:

On elasticnode01:

```
network.host: elasticnode01
```

On elasticnode02:

```
network.host: elasticnode02
```

Comment: So, I just add each of them to elasticsearch.yml file?

Comment: Yes and then you restart each nodes. They should discover each other, provided you changed your hosts file on both servers.

Comment: To the one who downvoted, please enlighten us and tell us what itches ;-)